1950s Sci-Fi involving a strange box that transports a boy to a different world
I'm looking for the name of a black and white 1950s science fiction movie... it starts out with a man who finds a small black box with a little cone on one side at a construction site dig. A little boy, I think his son, asks to keep the box. He takes this box home and somehow drops it and it shatters into pieces. He goes to sleep with a piece of the object in his hand and next thing we know he teleports to a different world. He convinces someone in his family about this experience and takes them to this other world and they find many of these black boxes. They find a dead humanoid with headgear that has a wire connected to one of these boxes. They put the head gear on and find out information that is contained in the box. The information they learn is about 2 different planets which are at war.  
They then are able to teleport from planet to planet when they stand on a round platform. I thought it was called the Terminots or something like that.

You might have better luck identifying this movie on SFF.

It's a 1960's movie name "The Terrornauts".
The Terrornauts is a 1967 science fiction film produced by Amicus Productions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terrornauts
Just watched it on youtube... just as I remembered except it was in color...
We must have only had a black and white TV at the time.



